# Simple XML using CDATA

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, cdata

I'm trying to write to XML using SimpleXML but I need html tags to be held in my XML tags.
Here's my code:

```
class SimpleXMLExtended extends SimpleXMLElement 
{ 
    public function addCData($cdata_text) 
    { 
        $node= dom_import_simplexml($this); 
        $no = $node->ownerDocument; 
        $node->appendChild($no->createCDATASection($cdata_text)); 
    } 
} 


$xml = new SimpleXMLExtended('<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?><xml></xml>'); 

$model->addChild('type')->addCData($type['type']);
$model->addChild('titleXML')->addCData($titleXML['titleXML']);
$model->addChild('features')->addCData($features['features']);
$model->addChild('options')->addCData($options['options']);
$model->addChild('gallery')->addCData($gallery['gallery']);
$model->addChild('info')->addCData($info['info']);

echo('XML: '.$xml->asXML());
```

I keep on getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in ... .../admin/addprocess.php on line 148

Ideas?

Comment: it should be $xml->addChild(), or change $xml to $model

Comment: Ahhh that fixed it partially.

Now its writing to the XML tags, however only the first charachter shows up.

Comment: @EricKlassen: Where's `$type` array?

Comment: $type = $_POST["type"];
$type isn't an array

Comment: @EricKlassen If `$type` isn't an array, then why are you accessing a key from it with `$type['type']`? PHP will interpret that as accessing a character from a string by its offset; since `'type'` isn't a number, it will coerce it to `0`, which is why you get the first character of your string.